# Compute in closed form that $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form, digamma-function

Compute the following sum :

S=$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n}$

My attempt : 
Use partial fraction :

$6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n=n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)$
$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{9(2n+1)}{7(3n^2+3n-1)}-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{1+n}+\frac{16}{7(2n+1)})$
Then use identity digamma " sum "
But I find divergence sum

Comment: Please provide the partial fractions decomposition that you determined.

Comment: If you multiply $n(n+1)(2n+1)(n^3+3n-1)$, the coefficient of $n^6$ is $2$,but original polynomial has $6$ and $n^5$. Try to fix this.

Comment: Your sum should be $$3/7\,\tan \left( 1/6\,\pi\,\sqrt {21} \right) \pi-6/7\,\Psi \left( 1/2
+1/6\,\sqrt {21} \right) -6/7\,\gamma+{\frac {16\,\ln  \left( 2
 \right) }{7}}
$$

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Grubner thank you .

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$$6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n=6n(n+1)\left(n+\frac12 \right)\left(n+\frac{\sqrt{21}+3}{6} \right)\left(n-\frac{\sqrt{21}-3}{6} \right)$$
Use partial fraction decomposition and  generalized harmonic numbers or polygamma functions.

**Edit**

Whatever the denominator will be, after partial fraction decomposition, you have
$$\frac 1 {P_k(n)}=\sum_{i=1}^k \frac {a_i}{n-r_i}$$ and
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p \frac {1}{n-r_i}=\psi (p+1-r_i)-\psi (1-r_i)$$ Now, using asymptotics
$$S_p=\log (p)-\psi
   (1-r_i)+\frac{1-2r_i}{2p}-\frac{6 r_i^2-6 r_i+1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ You just need to recombine everything and continue with Taylor expansions to get not only the limit but also how it is approached.

For sure, the limit will be finite only if $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i=0$.

As an example, consider
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{2}{3}\right) \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)
   \left(n+\frac{5}{6}\right)}$$
$$\frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{2}{3}\right) \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)
   \left(n+\frac{5}{6}\right)}=\frac{216}{3 n+2}-\frac{576}{4 n+3}+\frac{432}{6 n+5}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{2}{3}\right) \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)
   \left(n+\frac{5}{6}\right)}=72 \psi \left(p+\frac{5}{3}\right)-144 \psi
   \left(p+\frac{7}{4}\right)+72 \psi \left(p+\frac{11}{6}\right)-72
   \psi \left(\frac{11}{6}\right)+144 \psi \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)-72
   \psi \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)$$ So, using the asymptotics, for infintely large values of $p$
$$\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{2}{3}\right) \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)
   \left(n+\frac{5}{6}\right)}=-72 \left(\psi \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)-2 \psi
   \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)+\psi
   \left(\frac{11}{6}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{2
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you .. But then we find div sum

Comment: @Rozeflowers. Sum from $2$ to $p$ and use asymptotics for large values of $p$.

Comment: Sum from 1 to p then $\lim_{p\to +\infty} S_p$ ?

Comment: For example : how I find $\sum_1^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1})=?$

Comment: @Rozeflowers. This is the way. Concerning your last comment, I shall answer tomorrow (here, it is 8:15pm) ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudLeibovici OK  will Wait for you ..thanks!